# Accessing XML-File in Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, path

I just want to access a simple XML-File in Android-Studio. It shouldn't be a problem, but somehow my path is not correct. The file I want to access is the `persons.xml` file in the above image. I am using this path:

```java
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("../../assets/persons.xml");
} catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
    f.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I get a file not found exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../assets/persons.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).`

When I'm using the same path in my console I have no problems opening the file.

Comment: If your `persons.xml` file is in `assets/` of your project, use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on the asset. There is no means of getting an `OutputStream`, as assets are read-only at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I need to write to the file as well, so I have to put it in a regulary directory?

Comment: What you write would need to be to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or possibly [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You can use the asset as a source of initial data -- if your file does not exist on the filesystem, read from the asset.